# Building a generic filter parameter inputs interface?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

I have method calls that take different inputs, i.e:

```
public Authors GetAuthors(string name, string sortBy, string sortDir, int startRow, int numRow)
{
    // Get authors based on filters
}

public Books GetBooks(string id, string year, string sortBy, string sorDir, int startRow, int numRow)
{
    // Get books based on filters
}
```

I'm planning to change it so that the filters are objects, i.e:

```
public Authors GetAuthors(GetAuthorsFilters filters)
{
    // Get authors based on filters
}

public Books GetBooks(GetBooksFilters filters)
{
    // Get books based on filters
}
```

But many filters are common across the methods, and I would like to build an generic interface for this (i.e `IFilter`) that can take different filter objects, but not sure where to start. Any suggestion or recommendation?

Thanks.

Comment: Perfect exmaple for Specification Pattern. Check this link: http://devlicio.us/blogs/jeff_perrin/archive/2006/12/13/the-specification-pattern.aspx

Comment: Thanks Cybernate, I'll check out the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, I'd use an abstract class to complish what you are looking for.  You could create an interface for each search type, but then you have to implement the interface everytime, and it appears that there isn't a programatic difference between your shared properties in BookFilters and AuthorFilters.  Maybe something like:

```
public abstract class BaseFilter
{
    public string SortBy { get; set; }
    public bool SortAscending { get; set; }
    public int RowStart { get; set; }
    public int RowCount { get; set; }
}

public class BookFilter : BaseFilter
{
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}

public class AuthorFilter : BaseFilter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [An anonymous user suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/234938) you use [the ListSortDirection enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.listsortdirection.aspx) instead of `bool SortAscending`.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to have some shared functionality between all of the filters.  The way you would want to implement this is not necessarily through an interface, but rather through an abstract base class.  Additionally, because you will be filtering on different objects, it would make sense to use generics.  You could have something like the following:

```
public class FilterBase<T> {
    protected int startRow;
    ...

    public FilterBase(Func<T, IComparable> sortBy, bool sortAscending, int startRow, int numRow) {
        //assigns to member variables
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Filter(IEnumerable<T> toFilter) {
        filtered = DoFiltering(toFilter);
        filtered = DoPaging(filtered);
        filtered = DoSorting();
        return filtered;
    }

    protected abstract IEnumerable<T> DoFiltering(IEnumerable<T> toFilter);
    protected virtual IEnumerable<T> DoPaging(IEnumerable<T> toFilter) {
        return toFilter.Skip(startRow).Take(numRow);
    }
    protected virtual IEnumerable<T> DoSorting(IEnumerable<T> toFilter) {
        return sortAscending ? toFilter.OrderBy(sortBy) : toFilter.OrderByDescending(sortBy);
    }
}

public class BookFilter : FilterBase<Book> {
    public BookFilter(string id, string year, string sortBy, string sorDir, int startRow, int numRow) : base(sortBy, sorDir, startRow, numRow) {
        //assign id and year to member variables
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Book> DoFiltering(IEnumerable<Book> toFilter) {
        return toFilter.Where(b => b.Id == id && b.Year == year);
    }
}
```

This will allow you to define the paging and sorting logic once for all of the types of filter, and have each of the types define their own custom filtering based on their private members and the type of object they are referring to.